# Understanding Hibernate Logging Categories

Tags: hibernate, logging, categories

I'm having some trouble understanding the Hibernate logging categories.  I'm basing my assumptions on the documentation located at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging

I'm using log4j.properties to configure the logging level for Hibernate, using the following:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

outputs info for all categories of hibernate (org.hibernate.loader, org.hibernate.jdbc, org.hibernate.engine, etc).

What I'm really wanting is only the org.hibernate.SQL category to log at the DEBUG level.  I've tried various combinations of:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

But it never seems to "see" the SQL category, and only uses the org.hibernate logging level.

Is what I'm wanting to do even possible?  If so, what am I getting wrong in trying to make it work?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to specify your appender after `DEBUG`:-

Try this:-

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, CONSOLE_APPENDER  
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false 

log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks limc, I tried it with just DEBUG and with CONSOLE_APPENDER and seem to get the same results either way.  I wasn't able to find much about what the CONSOLE_APPENDER option does, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The CONSOLE_APPENDER is basically just some appender name I use. The name is not important as long as you use it to refer to your existing appender... see the `Configuration` section at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: @ryan: by the way, if this log4j thing doesn't work for you, you can still spit out the SQL by setting `hibernate.show_sql` property to `true`... see this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional ... just want to lay another option here for you.